# Change the warning message from an external function

Tags: r

I want to change the warning message produced by a function from another package while still getting the result. I have figured out the following but I wonder if there is a better way or if someone can explain `invokeRestart` which I have used but don't really understand

```r
f <- function(){
  warning("warning message from external fun that I can't edit")
  "result of fun that I still want"
}

withCallingHandlers(warning = function(cnd) {
  
  warning("my new warning")
  invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  }, f()
)
```